# Unbold the citations

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, books

I want to cite articles of bibliography using abbreviations as labels instead of numbers.

Looking in the Internet I found the commands below to do that.

The problem now is that the outputs are bold labels which I do not want. How can I unbold all the citations?

P.S. I know that there is another topic open but it is related to amsproc class while I am using the simple book class.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 

%These commands serve to cite with abbreviations instead of numbers
\usepackage[backend=biber,url=true,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{citekey}
  }
}

\begin{document}

... allow us to prove theorems 3.1 and 4.1 of \cite{author};

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{author} Authorname
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you run biber?

Comment: `biblatex` does nothing at all if you directly include a `thebibliography` environment.

Comment: @egreg: ok I didn't know that and I am ok in using directly thebibliography environment; how can I fix the bold citation problem?

Comment: @Tommaso Remove the call to `biblatex`.

Comment: Either you don't use `biblatex` and have to do everything manually with `thebibliography`; or you use `biblatex` and drop `thebibliography` in favour of `\printbibliography` you will have to compile with Biber in that case, see [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you want

```
\printbibliography
```

here's a complete MWE, complete with `arara` directives (just for example).

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 

%These commands serve to cite with abbreviations instead of numbers
\usepackage[backend=biber,url=true,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{cmh.bib}
@online{author,
title="minimum working example",
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{cmh.bib}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{citekey}
  }
}

\begin{document}

... allow us to prove theorems 3.1 and 4.1 of \cite{author};

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you but the problem still is there. In the body of the text, the citation appears in bold style while I want it in plain style. So, I am ok in using directly thebibliography environment instead of biblatex, provided that I will be able to have plain citations, not bold.